# Can't deploy war to Weblogic--server is unable to resolve classpath ejb-refs that aren't mine

Tags: maven, weblogic, ejb, classpath, jersey

I have a Maven application `.war` that I am using the [Weblogic Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/weblogic-maven-plugin/) for (great plugin, btw), and I am deploying it to a Weblogic server (of course).  Unfortunately, I keep getting a deploy failure message:

`weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: [J2EE:160200]Error resolving ejb-ref 'com.vendor.thing.UsingHelloWorldEJB/h' from module 'myapp.war' of application 'myapp'. The ejb-ref does not have an ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target bean has not been specified. Attempts to automatically link the ejb-ref to its target bean failed because no EJBs in the application were found to implement the 'com.vendor.thing.HelloWorld' interface. Please link or map this ejb-ref to its target EJB and ensure the interfaces declared in the ejb-ref are correct.`

### Huh?

This `HelloWorld` EJB isn't part of my application, and the only place that I know this class exists for Weblogic to even reference it is in a classpath jar that I use within the .war.  This is a vendor `.jar`, so it makes sense that they might have some classes that I don't use or know about.  In this case, it appears they bundled an EJB class into the `.jar` that I can't remove.

### Why?

I'm not a Weblogic expert, so this behavior is odd to me.  Is this standard servlet behavior to try to link and then fail a .war deploy based on some arbitrary class EJB's that aren't directly a part of my .war (other than as an API .jar in the classpath)?

### How to fix?

How can I get my `.war` deployed to the Weblogic server?  I don't know anything about this `ejb-ref`, nor does it seem to affect anything in how my app works when running locally with [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/).  Is there a way to tell Weblogic to ignore all classes in this `.jar` or package scope?

## EDIT 1

Per [mhaller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543054/cant-deploy-war-to-weblogic-server-is-unable-to-resolve-classpath-ejb-refs-that/4543080#4543080), I did some more investigation and found that:

- weblogic-maven-plugin uses the .war generated from the maven-war-plugin, so it doesn't interfere with the generation of the war.
- There are no additional deployment descriptors (no `weblogic.xml` or similar) other than my web.xml.
- manually deploying the `.war` behaves no differently than using the maven plugin (so I think the weblogic-maven-plugin isn't causing the fault)

### My `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.mypacakages.ws</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <!-- All web services will be under http://localhost:{port}/{context}/ws/ -->
      <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check if the final `.war` file contains additional deployment descriptors, which you do not need. I suspect the maven-weblogic-plugin adds custom deployment descriptors.
- Use `maven-war-plugin` instead.